# Requirement of old passport for visa for travelling to schengen countries

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, passport-renewals

As i have lost my old passport, and there was no travelling or any visa alotted on that passport, now i want to apply for schengen visa, would they ask for my old passport?

Comment: Don't think they will ask, unless you had a previous Schengen visa. But some other countries might ask if you have lost a passport, probably US and UK do.

Comment: But either way the answer that it was lost and replaced should be a good enough answer. Mine was stolen in 2002, and from time to time they ask me at immigration about it (yes, still), and I answer them it was stolen and a police report filed, and they are fine with it.

Comment: @Aganju that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

If they would ask, the answer that it was lost and replaced should be a good enough answer.

Mine was stolen in 2002, and from time to time they ask me at immigration about it (yes, still), and I answer them it was stolen and a police report filed, and they are fine with it (and they never wanted to see the policy report)